# What is the meaning of quote = "" in count.fields function in R?

Tags: r

I dont understand the meaning of quote="" or quote=" \ " ' " in the count.fields function. Can someone please explain the use of the quote field and difference between the above two values of quote field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the text file

```
one two
'three four'
"file six"
seven "eight nine"
```

which we can create with

```
lines <- c(
  "one two",
  "'three four'",
  "\"file six\"",
  "seven \"eight nine\"")
writeLines(lines, "test.txt")
```

The `quote=` parameter lets R know what characters can start/end quoted values within the file. We can ignore quotes all together by setting `quote=""`. Doing that we see

```
count.fields("test.txt", quote="")
# [1] 2 2 2 3
```

so it's interpreting the spaces as starting new fields and each word is it's own field. This might be useful if you have fields that contain quotes for things other than creating strings. Such as last names like `o'Brian` and measurements like `5'6"`. If we just say only double quotes start string values, we get

```
count.fields("test.txt", quote="\"")
# [1] 2 2 1 2
```

So here the first two lines are the same but line 3 is considered to have just one value. The space between the quotes does not start a new field.

The default is to use either double quotes or single quotes which gives

```
count.fields("test.txt")
# [1] 2 1 1 2
```

So now the second line is treated like third line as having just one value

Answer (score 1):

`cat` is often a good way to show what you are dealing with when you have quotes inside quotes.

```
> cat("Nothing:", "", "\n")
Nothing:  
> cat("Something:", "\"'", "\n")
Something: "'
```

The first example of `quote=""` is specifying you have no quotes in the file.
The second example of `quote="\"'"` is specifying you have `"` or `'` as potential quoting fields.

The `\` backslash is used to 'escape' the following character so `\"` is treated literally as `"` instead of closing off the argument to `quote=` prematurely.